# Laravel Broadcasting Private Channel - broadcasting/auth error 500

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

i am facing an 500 error when i try to listen to an event.
I am using laravel as backend and vuejs as frontend, I am kinda newbie about vuejs and pusher the back and front end are in separated projects.
I have multiple guard such as but the admin admin user guards are what i am focusing on.
i want to listen for a broadcast events from my vueJs.
this is how configured back end.

this is how i call the event from the controller

```
    $message = new Message();
    $message->textContent = $request->message;
    $message->isSent = true;
    $message->conversation_id = $conversation->id;
    $message->save();
    broadcast(new MessageSent($message));
```

this is how i defined a broadcastOn method

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('conversation.10');
}
```

this is the channels that the event should broadcast

```
Broadcast::channel('conversation.{message_id}', function ($user,$id) {
    return true;
});
```

I edited BroadcastServiceProvider to

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

i believe that users must be authorized to listen on private channels this is why i used return true, to avoid authentification problem.

this is how i initialized in the front end

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'keyGoesHere',
  cluster: 'eu',
  encrypted: true,
  authEndpoint: 'http://www.backend.test/broadcasting/auth',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }
})
```

Then i listen to event from the compenent this way

```
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('chat/setChatSearchQuery', '');
    Echo.channel(`private-conversation.10`)
      .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
        console.log("event");
      });
  }
```

The console shows

```
POST http://www.backend.test/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: make `encrypted: false` and check in network tab error in detail

Answer (score -1):

i made encrypted: false the network tab error shows

```
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```